# Signing and build types

Tags: android, build, gradle, sign

Has anyone found reason for not put signing config specification to flavour instead of build config? As for me next config:

```
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      lintOptions {
        lintConfig file( 'lint-development-rules.xml' )
        abortOnError false
      }
    }

    release {
      runProguard true
      proguardFile file( 'proguard-rules.txt' )

        lintConfig file( 'lint-production-rules.xml' )
        abortOnError true
    }
  }

  productFlavors {
    develop {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

      buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_URL', '"DEV URL"'
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEVELOPER_MODE', 'true'

      applicationId android.defaultConfig.applicationId + '.debug'
    }

    market {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release

      buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_URL', '"PROD URL"'
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEVELOPER_MODE', 'false'
    }
```

It is more logical since I can build debuggable production apk (without gradle file modification) and replace with it obfuscated production apk on the device without data loss.